# Titanium app crashes when removing pages from ScrollableView

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I have an app that uses a `ScrollableView` with dynamically added pages. I have a function that removes the views. If I haven't changed pages in the `ScrollableView` the pages are removed OK. However, if I scroll to a different page i.e not the first page, then try to remove the pages the app crashes. It's fine on iOS but it's Android that I'm having the problem on.

Here's the function that removes the views from the `ScrollableView`.

```
function emptyScrollView(){
    var views = $.bookables_scroll.views;
    var count = views.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        $.bookables_scroll.removeView(views[i]);
        $.bookables_scroll.views[i] = null;
    }
}
```

This is the code that adds a view to my `ScrollableView`

```
var payload = {
    bookable : bookable,
    rota: b_rota,
    current_date: current_date,
};

// adds to scrollable view
$.bookables_scroll.addView(Alloy.createController('appointments_bookable', payload).getView());
```

Why is the app crashing when I remove a view/page after having scrolled away from the first one?

Titanium v3.4.0
Alloy v1.5.1

Comment: what error msg do you see in the console?

Comment: Alloy + Titanium version too

Comment: @phil updated my Q with the versions. I don't get an error in the console. I just get popup "Unfortunately, App Name has stopped".

Comment: check error in logcat, there would be some. also how are you calling `emptyScrollView()`, can you show some code.

Answer (score 0):

if ($.bookables_scroll && $.bookables_scroll.children != undefined) {

```
// Save childrens
var removeData = [];

for (i = $.bookables_scroll.children.length; i > 0; i--) {
    removeData.push($.bookables_scroll.children[i - 1]);
};

// Remove childrens
for (i = 0; i < removeData.length; i++) {
    $.bookables_scroll.remove(removeData[i]);
}
removeData = null;
```

}

Try to save children view into an array then use another loop to remove all pages in scrollable view.

Hope it helps.

Thank you

Comment: That doesn't work. ```$.bookables_scroll.children``` is showing as an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after trying many removal ways, I ended up with removing all the listeners of that  scrollableview, removing it, removing its childs with removeAllChildren, cleaning each of his child controllers and creating a new one with the new child views and replacing it. Yes, it's not the best way but the component kept crashing with any other things I tried.

Answer (score 0):

its a bug in Titanium  ScrollableView , and its fixed in SDK 5.4.0 as they confirm in Jira

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20116